# How to make an 8TB protected SHR from a 4TB unprotected SHR (Synology Hybrid RAID)?

Tags: raid, synology

I have a 2-bay Synology Disk Station (DS220j) with a single 4TB Drive in it. There is a SHR Volume 1 on the system. It's currently without protection but it was prepared for another 4TB drive to be added.

As time passed, 4TB is not sufficient anymore and I'm wondering if I can upgrade the DS this way:

1. Add a 8TB drive into the SHR and let it sync. The capacity will be still 4TB but now protected.
2. Remove the 4TB drive. Now the capacity should be 8TB unprotected -- **is it right?**
3. Add a second 8TB drive dnd let is sync. Now the capacity should be 8TB protected -- **is it right?**

I'd like to ask if my assumptions above are right?

Comment: I am unaware of the device but you can try to set up a raid 1 with a missing device, copy the data from 4TB to 8TB and then remove and keep the 4TB securely. Add the second 8TB and let it sync, this should work in most cases. The Storage should be the keeper around 8TiB as it just makes a copy of the device for failover

Answer (score 0):

Synology's SHR RAID implementation is unique to them, and makes it easier to use disks with different sizes for a RAID. The process you described above will work,

Yes, add the 8TB drive. For step #2, when you remove the 4TB drive, your SHR RAID will simply be in a degraded - but still usable - state. Add your 2nd 8TB drive, and let the volume heal, and you'll be all set.